# Tkinter Button info

Tags: tkinter

Im a beginner when it comes to Python.
and im studying hard everyday to understand how everything works.

Now my question is this.

With Tkinter I want to be able to return a Tkinter Button.
So for example.

When I click the button, the button stays down
and I cant access any more of the options on my Tkinter application until that one process is finished.

Is there anyway to multitask on a Tkinter application?

Thank You
Any info would be great:)

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand: you want the Tkinter application to halt until the process started by clicking the button completes?

Comment: Its close to what your saying ktodisco
But i want the button to return so i can also click other Tkinter Buttons 
Because when i click a Button.
The Button stays down and the GUI Halts until the following process is finished.
Is there anyway to click other Tkinter Buttons when another Tkinter Button is pressed?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Give me just a sec, gotta look up something and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thank You So Much Man:)
Your Such A Help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that Tkinter has threading or multiprocessing built into it, but Python does have both a [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) and a [threading module](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading).

In your callback for your Tkinter Button you could use one of these modules to spawn a new process or thread that will execute independently of your GUI, allowing it to function without interruption.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your help man.
your a lifesaver.

thank you for your time and patience my friend.
god bless.

Comment: @user1193746: be careful, though - tkinter is not thread safe. You can only access GUI objects and methods from the thread where `mainloop` is running. There are lots of resources on the web that discuss these issues.

Comment: thanks man ill keep that in mind.
thanks for the heads up man

Answer (score 2):

Call root.update()

You can do this once at the start of your function to make the button pop back up, or you can call it within a loop inside your function (if there is one) to keep the program from freezing up.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable that would change its value, once your process is started and finished. Then, make your button state change to `disabled` and `enabled` according to that variable changing its value. If you'd like, I could try to pass some code.